# FOSRestBundle ParamFetcher POST method

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm creating restful API with FOSRestBundle.
When I send data via ajax with using GET method, everything works ok.
But I have to send data by POST, I try to get values from POST with ParamFetcherListener, but it returns null values.
When I change the request method to GET, it works.
What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
/**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=201)
 * @QueryParam(name="test", description="test")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    $test = $paramFetcher->get('test'); // it's null
}
```

And config.yml:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener:
        decoders:
            json: fos_rest.decoder.json
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
        formats:
            xml: true
            json: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api/', priorities: ['json', 'xml'], fallback_format: 'html', prefer_extension: false }
```

Routing:

```
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                      
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                        
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                  
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar              
  _profiler_info             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}            
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                 
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results  
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                 
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router          
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception       
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css   
  _twig_error_test           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}           
  object_all                 GET      ANY      ANY    /api/objects                       
  saved_object_all           GET      ANY      ANY    /api/saved_objects                 
  saved_object_get           GET      ANY      ANY    /api/saved_objects/{id}            
  saved_object_new           POST     ANY      ANY    /api/saved_objects                 
  saved_object_delete        DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/saved_objects/{id}            
  object_test                ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/test
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are there any more annotations before method createAction?

Comment: you can see all routes in your application by calling `php bin/console debug:router` also please include to your question your routing config

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Routing included

Answer (score -3, accepted):

My mistake, of course data in POST requests is sent in body, body listener decoder is set, so this is the correct solution:

```
/**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=201)
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $test = $request->request->get('test'); 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution reverts to using the standard request object.

If you want to use ParamFetcher with a post request you need to use

```
@RequestParam
```

instead of

```
@QueryParam
```

in the annotation of your method.

```
/**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=201)
 * @RequestParam(name="test", description="test")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    $test = $paramFetcher->get('test'); // it's null
}
```